# SP with multiple results in EF 5 CF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm using Code First with EF 5. Currently I have SPs that return just single result to tie them with EF. And I wonder if it's possible to return multiple results using Code First? I read articles using DB First though. But there is nothing about CF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stored procedures with multiple result sets are currently supported only in EDMX (database first scenario). Moreover there is currently [no designer support](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1051207-design-time-support-for-multiple-results-in-stored) so you have to map them manually in XML.

Comment: Thank you, Ladislav.
yeah, read your post about DB First approach.